# subtraction in ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` in java called `ind` that contains indices of another ArrayList called `data`. What I want to do is to compare each item of ind with the following next ones, to see if the difference is lower than a number, `mpd`. If the difference is greater, go to the next item.
If it is lower, delete the index where `data.get(index)` is lowest.
Basically, I try to find the highest peak.

My first approach was this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<ind.size()-1; i++) {
        if (ind.get(i) != -1) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ind.size(); j++) {
                if ((ind.get(j) - ind.get(i)) <= mpd) {
                    if (x.get(ind.get(i)) >= x.get(ind.get(j))) {
                        ind.set(j, -1);
                    } else {
                        ind.set(i, -1);
                        break;
                    }
                 } else {
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
ind.removeAll(Collections.singleton(-1));
```

I know it's not the best way to remove an item from the list, but this did the job at first.

But I know there has to be a much better way to do this.
So after doing some trying, I got to this:

```
ind.removeIf(indices -> ((ind.get(indices+1) - ind.get(indices)) <= mpd));
```

Which is great but, of course, for the last comparison, where it is out of bounds. And it doesn't do the comparison to delete the element that is highest

`(x.get(ind) vs x.get(ind+1))`

Is there any way I can compare an item and its succesors in a list and afterwards their value in another list that does not imply a double for loop?
Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:**

After doing some thinking, I'm not sure this is possible since indices contains the values of ind, so if I do `indices+1` it will just add 1, but not get the next value, and I cannot do indices.next()

Comment: Can't you just stop one element early, so you don't run off the edge?

Comment: Do you want to remove the indices at the end or immediately after you found them. I believe they might end to different results.

Comment: You say you want to compare current ind with the one after, but your code is comparing current ind with every ind after that.  At the end of your question, you say you are looking for highest peak.  I'm not fully understanding the problem.

Comment: @NickZiebert that is correct, sorry about that. I want to compare with every item after that. I want to have only one element on each window (set by mpd). If the next element is greater than the threshold, go to the next one.

Comment: @PeymanMahdian I want to remove them immediately if possible, but doing it at the end would also work. What is easiest and takes less computational effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check that you are still in bounds

```
ind.removeIf(indices -> (indices + 1 < ind.size() && (ind.get(indices) - ind.get(indices + 1)) <= mpd));
```

You can't really use removeIf as that can only remove the current index you are iterating on and you need to compare that to all others (in your original code the comparison may result in removing the current node or the one you are comparing it to).  For this same reason a ListIterator doesn't help either.  You could remove the inner for loop however:

```
    Integer lastInd = null;
    Integer lastData = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<ind.size(); i++) {
        // New peak value with no removal
        if (i == 0 || ind.get(i) - lastData > mpd) {
            lastInd = i;
            lastData = ind.get(i);
            continue;
        }
        // Remove the lower value, if lower value was lastData switch to
        // make this value the new lastData for comparison
        if (x.get(lastData) >= x.get(ind.get(i))) {
            ind.set(i, -1);
        } else {
            ind.set(lastInd, -1);
            lastInd = i;
            lastData = ind.get(i);
        }
    }
    ind.removeAll(Collections.singleton(-1));
```

Comment: That is a great idea that I hadn't even thought about... Any idea if it's possible to do a quick comparison.
I tried 
`ind.removeIf(indices -> ((indices + 1 < ind.size()) && (ind.get(indices) - ind.get(indices + 1)<= mpd) && (x.get(indices) < x.get(indices+1))));`

thinking it might remove the element only if it's smaller than the predecessor, but I don't think it's working properly.

Comment: It might be useful to understand what you are doing, perhaps with some data - I am assuming that x in your code is what you refer to as data in your description.  If you have mpd = 3, ind  = [ 3,6,5,1,7,2,4 ] and data = [ 6,9,2,8,1,3,5 ] then the result of your original code would be [2,6] I believe ( the highest value of 9 is lost because of the mpd check).  Is that the result you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific - the result of your original code would be ind =[ 3,1 ] pointing to data being 2 and 6 respectively

Comment: I am trying to do a peak detector. Yes, x is my data. Let's assume I have data = [1,4,2,3,0,3,2,7], then I have ind = [1,3,5,7], because those are the peaks. If mpd is 3, I want:
1. check ind. 1 and 3 are in the same window, so
2. see which peak is higher. data[1] is higher than data[3], so erase the ind entry
Do the same for the whole list. Finally, I'd have ind=[1,7]
I hope that helps